# In solidity, keccak 256 function returns a hash value. How many bits does keccak 256 return?

Tags: solidity, keccak

I used the following command :
keccak256('abc', 'pqr', 123);
I get a value once I run this. 
How many bit value is this?

Comment: Maybe you want to ask this on http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Never mind the output length, what values does it use for bitrate, capacity, and domain suffix?

Answer (score 6):

Keccak-256 in Solidity returns a 32 byte array (which could also be represented as a 256 bit string), as described in the [Solidity Documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/solidity/develop/solidity.pdf).